# Electron desktop app and Vue.js CSP settings

Tags: vue.js, electron, content-security-policy

I have this CSP setting for my vue-electron powered app:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';" />
```

This is not the safest way to use vue, but it's the quickest solution I've found to let the DOM work with vue mustache syntax `{{ value }}`. Is it possible to use vue without modify the CSP to `unsafe-inline` and `unsafe-eval` ?